# Retrofit Response with dynamic JSON array names

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit

In my case I have the following json response:

```
{
    "all": {
        "loc1": [
            {
                "userId": "1",
                "userName": "user1"
            },
            {
                "userId": "2",
                "userName": "user2"
            },
            {
                "userId": "2",
                "userName": "user2"
            },
            {
                "userId": "1",
                "userName": "user1"
            },
            {
                "userId": "2",
                "userName": "user2"
            }
        ],
        "loc2": [
            {
                "userId": "1",
                "userName": "user1"
            },
            {
                "userId": "2",
                "userName": "user2"
            },
            {
                "userId": "2",
                "userName": "user2"
            },
            {
                "userId": "1",
                "userName": "user1"
            },
            {
                "userId": "2",
                "userName": "user2"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

But now, the names of the arrays loc1 and loc2 are dynamically created. How can I get the response of the "all" json array and in addition to that the names of the dynamically created arrays. I tried something like this:

```
class EventResponse() {
    @SerializedName("all")
    val events: List<List<Event>> = mutableListOf()
}
```

But I get an error:

Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT.

How can I get dynamically created arrays and their names too?

Comment: How were you able to handle these dynamic array names? I am also using Retrofit and GSON

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in that case you can use JSONObject for getting dynamic value just convert retrofit response to JSONObject for that you have to change response type of retrofit Call

```
Call<ResponseBody> call = exampleApi();

call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {

  @Override
  public void onResponse(Response<ResponseBody> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
  String result = response.body().string();
  JSONObject object = new JSONObject(result);

 // can get any value from keys
 // for example in your case
  JSONArray array1 =  object.getJSONObject('all').getJSONArray('loc1');
 //similarly just change key to loc2 and so on

  JSONArray array2 =  object.getJSONObject('all').getJSONArray('loc2');

 }

 @Override
 public void onFailure(Throwable t) { 

   }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for that. But I get the ResponseBody object with "response.body.toString()".. (okhttp3.ResponseBody$1@82fdf53). And with this I can't create the JSONObject :(

---EDIT

My mistake. I used .toString instead of .string. It solved my problem thank you so much!

Comment: it is not fixed then how to get undefined size of array?
loc1 loc2 may be come 3,4,5 then how to get ?

Comment: @RameshKumar if keys name are not defined you can  get all key set using object.keys() and get respective object.

Comment: @bhardwaj  thank yopu for your response. Can you send any link where i can see full info about it?

Comment: @RameshKumar you can read https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject methods